# Insert nested objects into KieSession

Tags: performance, session, object, nested, drools

I have the following scenario in Drools:

```
package test;

public class A {
   public ArrayList<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();
}

public class B {
   public ArrayList<C> c = new ArrayList<C>();
   public ArrayList<D> d = new ArrayList<D>();
}

public class C {
   some attributes
}

public class D {
   some attributes
}
```

When I'm going to insert those facts into the KieSession, in order to make them available straight into the working memory, I have to iterate through all over the object, i.e:

```
for( int i=0; i< a.getB().size(); i++ ){
    ksession.insert(a.getB().get(i));
    for( int j=0; j< a.getB().get(i).getC().size; j++ ){
         ksession.insert(a.getB().get(i).getC().get(j));
         etc...
    }
}
```

In my understanding you have to do this if you don't want to access to one object through its parent, i.e.:

```
rule "Do something with B"
    when
        B()
    then
        ....
end
```

Instead of

```
rule "Do something with B"
    when
       A.b()
then
       ....
end
```

My question is: is there any way to load all the nested facts in a faster way than loads of nested FOR LOOP?

I hope my question makes sense.

Thank you for you feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Written using slicker Java statements it doesn't look so bad:

```
for( B b: a.getB() ){
     for( C c: b.getC() ) ksession.insert( c );
     for( D d: b.getD() ) ksession.insert( d );
     ksession.insert( b );
}
```

Drools will not "flatten" a recursive set of collections - how could any SW read your mind when you want the List of Cs expanded but not the List of Ds?

It may not be necessary to do this for all lists or down to the last level. The `from` clause may be the better option in some cases when writing rules that need to refer to child objects in a collection.

Also, review your object model. It may not be the best decision to have these lists collecting child objects. There are many ways to represent a graph, and some are closer to some Normal Form by avoiding repetitive fields, and this will also help when writing rules.